# Finding the row in an numpy array that has the smallest values compared to all other rows

Tags: python, numpy, row, minimum

say i have the following matrix:

```
A = [[7,5,1,2]
     [10,1,3,8]
     [2,2,2,3]]
```

I need to extract the row with elements closest to 0 compared to all other rows, aka the row with the minimal elements. So i need [2,2,2,3]

I have tried a number of things, np.min, np.amin, np.argmin

But all are giving me the minimum values of each row for example:

```
[2,1,1,2]
```

This is not what im looking for.

If someone knows the right function could you point me to the documentation of the function?

Thank you.

Comment: *the row with elements closest to 0 compared to all other rows* How do you  define this ?

Comment: @Cresht, its a np array though, dont i need to use np functions on an np array? @Psidom, im not sure how else to define it, like you know how in least squares we find the point closest to all other points? i need the row closest to `[0,0,0,0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define distance when you say *closest*. I'm guessing you are looking for the *Euclidean distance*, i.e. L2 norm here. In which case, you can just find the minimum sum of square for all rows:

```
A[(A ** 2).sum(1).argmin()]
# array([2, 2, 2, 3])
```

You can also find the *closest* by L1 norm or the sum of absolute difference against 0s:

```
A[np.abs(A).sum(1).argmin()]
# array([2, 2, 2, 3])
```

In this dummy example, the two methods give the same result, but they could be different depending on the actual data.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[7,5,1,2],
             [10,1,3,8],
             [2,2,2,3]])

print(print(A[np.argmin(A.sum(axis=1))]))

# [2 2 2 3]
```

Sum the rows, then find the row index of the minimum value, and finally find the row.

Answer (score 0):

The first way that comes to mind is to find the minimum of each row. Then find the argmin of that array.

```
row_mins = A.min(axis=0)
row_with_minimum = row_mins.argmin()
```

Then to get the row with the minimum element, do

```
A[row_with_minimum, :]
```